# How to Remove Last History in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have logout button on my site, When clicked their authentication is removed and they are sent back to the home page.

I was using

```
browserHistory.push({ pathname: '/home' });
```

but I noticed that if I would hit the "back" button after being logged out they would sort of go back to the previous logged in page(they would see nothing as they have no authentication).

I would like to remove the history so they can't go back.

So I tried

```
browserHistory.replace({ pathname: '/home' });
```

this also did not work.

Comment: `if (!isLoggedIn()) {
  return <Redirect to="/login" />;
}`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible.

I'd recommend you to check user auth on pages that require users to be authenticated and redirect them to the login page using `browserHistory.replace`. So if the user clicks back after logout the will see login page again.

Comment: Well is that what I am doing? When the user clicks on my logout, I have browserHistory.replace({ pathname: '/home' });

Comment: When you use `browserHistory.replace` it only replaces the current location with a new one. But all the previous history records remained.
I wanted to say that you should check user authentication via route's `onEnter` hook (for React Router v3) or via `componentDidMount` in your authenticated pages (for React Router v4) and replace current location to the login page if a user is not authenticated.

Comment: Well I do a check in componentDidMount but the problem is that it only get fired once. So if User Logins -> (now In members area) -> signs out -> now on login page and hits the back button which would go back to /members no componentDidMount is trigged as it was already mounted.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. As I understand you check user auth on the app level during mounting of some kind of root component. You can add `isLoggedIn` key to the top level state, set it to true after successful login, to false after logout and check it in `componentDidMount` method of pages that require authentication. Or create a HOC to perform this check. There is a variety of methods that should be selected depending on your auth method, state management approach, react router version and so on.
I can't give more detailed recommendations without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Hi It's great to see your progress while implementing optimized authentication in your app. You need to make sure that your history stack is maintained properly. I think you have always used `history.push` even going back. This is going to make a trouble. Try to use `goBack(), go(n)` for programmatically and for browser back button use `replace, push` where needed. You history stack should be aligned with browser back button.

Comment: Thanks for the post, I do use Push for a lot of things but mostly this is going back to Login page when autnetication failed. As I can't guarantee that is the last page in their history. I however will go back and check to see if there are any areas that maybe I should be using goback